# Loop with get and set?

Tags: java, loops, constructor, getter-setter

I'm writing a program with two classes, one person class and one main. The person class use get and set for six people and then the main class ask for the names and then show the user the six names (in my example it only shows four). Is it possible to use a loop for this? I know I could use a list for this but it's for school and they want us to use constructors, set and get in the first week or so. The code now looks like this. Is this even possible with an example like this or do I need to use a list or an array?

PersonClass.java

```
public class PersonClass {

    private String namn;

    public void setNamn(String namn) {
        this.namn = namn;
    }

    public String getNamn() {
        return namn;
    }
}
```

MainClass.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PersonClass person1 = new PersonClass();
        PersonClass person2 = new PersonClass();
        PersonClass person3 = new PersonClass();
        PersonClass person4 = new PersonClass();

        String namn1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person 1!");
        person1.setNamn(namn1);
        String namn2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person 2!");
        person2.setNamn(namn2);
        String namn3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person 3!");
        person3.setNamn(namn3);
        String namn4 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person 4!");
        person3.setNamn(namn4);


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person 1: " + person1.getNamn() +
                "\nPerson 2: " + person2.getNamn() + "\nPerson 3: " + person3.getNamn() +
                "\nPerson 4: " + person4.getNamn());
    }
}
```

Comment: Rename `PersonClass` to `Person`. It is already a class it is redundant to add `Class` in its name. Good names for functions, variables, and objects go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Hello because of your tone when suggesting arrays I take it that you are not comfortable with the concept yet, but maybe talk with your teacher about this and about the answers you get here!

```
    PersonClass[] personArray = {person1, person2, person3, person4};
    for (int i = 0; i < personArray.length; i++)
    {
        // (i + 1) because our array starts at 0, but it's the 0 + 1th person
        String msg = "Enter full name for person" + (i + 1);
        personArray[i].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(msg));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I said. We'll move on to arrays later on. Just looking for an answer if there is a possibility to loop with set and get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally a fan of Lists as well, but Arrays are just as good of an option. I build the output as it goes with a little `String.format` help.

```
    List<PersonClass> persons = new ArrayList<PersonClass>();
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(String.format("Enter full name for person %d!", i));
        PersonClass person = new PersonClass();
        person.setNamn(name);
        persons.add(person);
        output += String.format("Person %d: %s\n",i, person.getNamn());

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PersonClass[] persons = new PersonClass[4];
for(int i = 0; i < persons.length; i++){
    persons[i] = new PersonClass();
    persons[i].setNamn(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person " + (i+1));
}
```

If dialog will be closed - there will be `null` returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<PersonClass> people = new ArrayList<PersonClass>;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // set i to number of required people
    PersonClass person = new PersonClass();
    person.setNamn(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person " + (i + 1) +"!");

    people.add(person);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, person.getNamn());
}
```

`people` will contain all the new `PersonClass` you created.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this with a loop would be to make your main class like this. See comments:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<PersonClass> people = new ArrayList<PersonClass>(); 

        int index=5; 

        //Loop that will ask for 6 names
        for(int ii=0; ii<=index; ii++){

            //create person object
            PersonClass person = new PersonClass();

             //get/set the name
             person.setNamn(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person " + ii + " !"));

             //save name in arraylist
             people.add(person); 
        }

        int count = 1; 
        //will output names via a loop
        for(PersonClass person : people){
            if(person.getNamn() != null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person " + count + " name: " + person.getNamn());
            }   
            count++; 
        }
    }
}
```

If it were me, I'd create a custom constructor for the `PersonClass`, which sets the `namn` on construction:

```
public class PersonClass {

    private String namn;

    //Custom constructor using a setter
    public PersonClass(String namn){
       this.setNamn(namn); 
    }
    public void setNamn(String namn) {
        this.namn = namn;
    }

    public String getNamn() {
        return namn;
    }
}
```

Then I would do this in my `MainClass`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        ArrayList<PersonClass> people = new ArrayList<PersonClass>(); 

        int index=5; 

        //Loop that will ask for 6 names
        for(int ii=0; ii<=index; ii++){
             //create, set, and add name to list
             people.add(new PersonClass(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter full name for person " + ii + " !"))); 
        }





        int count = 1; 
        for(PersonClass person : people){
            if(person.getNamn() != null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Person " + count + " name: " + person.getNamn());
            }   
            count++; 
        }
    }
}
```